# Is it possible to send Array and Dictionary both into parameters at API hitting time using Alamofire Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, alamofire

I having the values like following.

```
let values = ["06786984572365", "06644857247565", "06649998782227"]
let params:[String:Any] = ["delete_wishlist_products":"1"]
```

Is any possible way for sending both dictionary and array as a params without headers, at API hitting time in Alamofire by using Swift.

Find my sample code here:

```
 func deleteWishlistValue(){
        
        let values = ["12345", "1345", "1234"]
        let params:[String:Any] = ["delete_wishlist_products":"1",
                                   "product_id":values,
                                   "customer_id":"152698"]
        
        Alamofire.request(Services.deleteWishlist,method: .get,parameters: params, headers:nil).responseJSON { (response) in
                            if response.result.error == nil{
                                print(response)
                            }else{
                                print(response.result.error?.localizedDescription ?? "")
                            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: show your sample API Params

Comment: $_GET['updatetocart']==1

In array i need

  qty
  product_id
  options_id

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example how to send array data in api using almofire

```
func getContest(arrDetails: [String],  completion: @escaping(_ reponse: ContestListResponse?, _ error: ApiError?)-> Void) {
    contestListRequest?.cancel()
    let parameters: Parameters = [
        "limit": "10",
        "details": arrDetails
        ]
let headers: HTTPHeaders = [
        "language": DBManager.getUserData()?.language ?? "eng"
    ]
    contestListRequest = Alamofire.request(AppURL.contestList, method:.post, parameters: parameters, encoding: JSONEncoding.default, headers: headers)
        .responseContestListResponse(completionHandler: { (response) in
            switch response.result {
            case .success(let result):
                print("result---",result)
                if response.response?.statusCode == 200 {
                    completion(result, nil);
                } else {
                    completion(result, ApiError(domain: .api, code: response.response?.statusCode ?? 0, msg: result.message ?? ""))
                }
            case .failure(let error):
                completion(nil, ApiError(domain: .system, code: error._code, msg: error.localizedDescription))
            }
        })
        .responseString { (response) in
            print(response.result.value ?? "NO Response")
    }
}
```

Change the response class and completion handler yourself.

Notice the `encoding: JSONEncoding.default` this is required from you for sending array or dict directly to parameters, ask your backend dev to get the properties accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Yes You just need to define an array, you are almost there, just need an extra set of [] in your dictionary. :

```
let values = [["product_id" : 06786984572365, "option_id" : 1]]
let params: [String: Any] = [
        "delete_wishlist_products":"1",
        "array":values,
        "customer_id":"152698"
    ]

Alamofire.request(Services.deleteWishlist,method: .get,parameters: params, headers:nil).responseJSON { (response) in
                            if response.result.error == nil{
                                print(response)
                            }else{
                                print(response.result.error?.localizedDescription ?? "")
                            }
        }
    }
```